# get cpu, disk, memory and network usage of applications running inside vm

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, cpu-usage, powercli

I am trying to get cpu usage, disk io, memory usage and network usage of all applications inside a virtual machine. I googled and find that for VM wise we can get the above data using powercli or powershell. But I want to get it from application level. If I have authentication to access the vm then what is the process or tools to monitor all those data at applications level?

Comment: nice talk about how "exact" %cpu is: https://opensource.com/article/18/4/cpu-utilization-wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you've remote access into the Windows VM. You can use PowerShell remoting.

```
$session = New-Pssession -ComputerName "127.0.0.1" -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Gives you a new remote session. You can use the `$session` object in `Invoke-Command`:

```
$cpu = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor }
```

On your local machine you can do:

```
Write-Host $cpu.Processor.LoadPercentage
```

To e.g. dump the CPU load.

You can also use [Get-Counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-5.1) to read Windows performance counter values. Depending on your destination Windows version, you may have to [enable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx) Powershell remoting.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried to connect through ur code in window powershell.  can you tell what are the parameters ..